# Reducing the cost of native <-> managed interactions in monotouch

Tags: c#, objective-c, performance, xamarin.ios

I'm playing with a native library for which I wrote monotouch (are we supposed to name that Xamarin.iOS now?) bindings.

Overriding some often used methods in C# shows a severe performance downgrade, even if the core of the function do nothing or return base.X (). Instruments confirms the problem and the time spend in managed<->native interactions.

Is there a way to speed that up, from one side or the other (native or managed) ? Or is this a tax to pay when P/Invoking in MT ?

The glass ceiling I'm hitting is about 50000 calls/sec.

**[UPDATE 2013/02/22]**
To give some context or example, here's what I'm doing. I'm playing with cocos2d kinematics (without chipmunk). To manage my own position of sprites, I have to override

```
CGAffineTransform NodeToParentTransform { get; }
```

and

```
bool Dirty { get; }
```

The former returns a matrices, and poke the native side to get parameters like ScaleX, ScaleY, RotationX. RotationY and AnchorPointInPoints, the latter return `true` unconditionally.

My attempt in reducing the cost is partly successful at this moment as, by changing the native code to have a single point to override which doesn't poke to any properties, I get a 25% to 50% speedup.

```
-(BOOL) dirty:(CGAffineTransform*)nodeToParentTransform rotationX:(float)rotX rotationY:(float)rotY scaleX:(float)scaleX scaleY:(float)scaleY anchorPointInPoints:(CGPoint)anchorPointInPoints;
```

I'm now getting an almost acceptable 25-30fps for my 3500 sprites, but I'd still like to go further. And also not have to patch the native sources.

**[UPDATE 2013/02/22 2]**
Here's a sample that you could use to test https://github.com/StephaneDelcroix/mt-speed. It contains an over simplified first order kinematic engine, 3501 bodies and sprites.

The interesting class here is `KinematicSprite`. The code as is works on a modified version of cocos2d (included in Cocos2D.dll). You can make it work on stock cocos2d and cocos2d bindings by commenting out the new `Dirty` function and uncommenting `NodeToParentTransform` and the old `Dirty`. As per [Subclassing bound type in mono touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962741/subclassing-bound-type-in-mono-touch), it only works on devices. I get 20 to 22.5 fps on an iPad mini.

Comment: How many calls a second if there was no managage<->native stuff going on?

Comment: All things being equals, if the method is overridden in native, it supports around 350000 call/sec

Comment: Can you show code for the method you invoke (with parameter types) and the results (screenshot?) from Instruments? The native-managed transition speed depends on a lot of factors (including the number of parameters and their types for instance).

Comment: Returning a (quite big) struct from a method (NodeToParentTransform) will use quite a few cpu cycles just copying data around. Can you use Instruments for the single overridden point to see where the time is spent there?

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix: a sample would be wonderful, I've been working on exactly this lately, so I might be able to find improvements somewhere.

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix I was not able to get your sample to run.   I get a crash, but I am wondering if this would be a case where adding a NodeToParent (ref parent) would help, by passing a pointer instead of copying the large affine.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza what crash do you get? It's known to crash on the simulator though (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962741/subclassing-bound-type-in-mono-touch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are we supposed to name that Xamarin.iOS now?

Yes, it's Xamarin.iOS now :-)

> Or is this a tax to pay when P/Invoking in MT ?

There's a lot of things do be done while transitioning from managed and unmanaged code. The trampolines take cares of this: marshaling parameters and return values, handling managed exception, handling native exception...

Also you might be doing the transition many times, e.g. `new Managed ();` calls native `init*` which calls (native) `setFoo:` which goes back to (managed) `Foo` setter (and back... to callers).

So even if each part is fast it can still be notable if you do a no-op (or just call `base`) since there's no much *user time* to amortize against.

> Is there a way to speed that up, from one side or the other (native or managed) ?

Yes. First make sure you measure the *real* thing. E.g.

- The above tasks differs from the simulator and devices, e.g. JIT versus AOT, different ABI for x86 and ARM;
- Debug and release build configuration will also use different code;

So you likely want to measure a Release build on an iOS (ARM) device.

The next thing you should do is to ensure **Link all assemblies** is enabled (if you have non-SDK bindings, e.g. Cocos2d). That won't change the trampolines but when you call `base` you're calling binding code.

And it turns out that the linker is *very smart* about bindings and can remove code that is not required in your situation. E.g.

- [remove checks and branches related to `IsDirectBinding`](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/linker-vs-bindings-and-isdirectbinding/);
- [remove code related to `NewRefCount` (sgen option)](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/linker-vs-bindings-and-newrefcount/);
- [remove checks and branches related to 'Runtime.Arch`](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/linker-vs-bindings-and-runtime-arch/);
- [remove checks for UI thread checks](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/linker-vs-bindings-and-runtime-arch/) (in case you inherit from UIKit); and
- any future optimization we add in the future :-)

**EDIT**: another reason to enable the linker is that it remove the extra (unused) methods in the bindings - making it less likely that the native code needs to call back into the managed world (and less transitions means faster times)

Other ways are more invasive and might require code changes to minimize the chatter between managed and native code. E.g. sometime you can call

```
var x = new X (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

or

```
var x = new X ();
x.a = 1;
x.b = 2;
x.c = 3;
x.d = 4;
```

You can guess the first case would require less transitions (and be faster). If such API does not exists then it *could* be added - but that should be a least resort option (there's likely other places where optimization would get you a larger pay off).

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix no rush but I'd be curious to know how you tested it and (mostly) what was the impact of enabling the linker on all the code :-)

Comment: Linking All doesn't really help, only marginally by a few 3 to 5 %. My next try will be to reduce the number of methods I need to override by providing a do-it-all native helper...

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your weird crash bug question, I notice that cocos2d code is jumping back into monotouch land all the time because the bindings export all the mono versions of every method with the objective-c name. I wonder if you could redo the bindings without those exposed and get a huge bump in speed?

It seems like you wouldn't need (or want, really) those exposed unless you override the specific methods - in which case you could add the objective-c exports in for your overridden method... I've not done this, and I don't know if it's asking for trouble. It just seems like things would work better if the objc side never called back unless you have custom code there.

Would love to hear a comment from poupou or other xamarin guys addressing this!

Comment: The linker, if enabled (**really it should be**), will remove the *extra* methods (and calls/transitions) so they won't get back into managed code (needlessly). That removes the crash (from the sample) but does not make the *face* appear.

Comment: The crash in **not** related to this issue. At all.

Comment: This wasn't so much about your crash, just something I noticed while looking at it. If you're using a binding that exports objective-c names on the methods, then when you call the objective-c code it may hop back over to c# and back again inside that call (objc calling [self color], etc), which overall is potentially a huge slowdown. As poupou said, you can make the empty ones go away by linking them out, but you will still have that issue on methods you override. So the cost of going across c#/objc is very dependent on how much the objc code uses methods on self.

Comment: The MonoTouch runtime does not work the way you think it does.   The only times when there is a transition from Objective-C to C# is when you explicitly override a method to alter its behavior, otherwise, the API definition is merely a consumption API.